# month(createdAt) in nodejs sequelize

Tags: php, node.js, sequelize.js

```sql
SELECT payslipid,
       CONCAT(fname, ' ', mname, ' ', surname) AS name,
       pay_start,
       pay_end,
       paymentmethod,
       payment_no,
       preparedby,
       gross_pay,
       created
FROM employee_info t1
INNER JOIN pay_slip t2 ON t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
WHERE MONTH(created) = '1' || MONTH(created) = '2' || MONTH(created) = '3'
GROUP BY created DESC
```

I'm trying to fetch the data using only the month of a date in createdAt using sequelize but I don't know how make it work. Do you know how to convert this php code into sequelize ? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure this SQL query is correct? I'm confused with `GROUP BY created DESC` How should it work? I don't see any aggregate functions at all

Comment: maybe it should be `ORDER BY created DESC `?